# How to copy const char* to uint8_t [] in c++?

Tags: c++

In the following example

```
const char* msg1 = "hello how are you";
```

I want to copy into `uint8_t msg2[]`

How to copy msg1 values into msg2?

Comment: `msg1` is way larger than `msg2` and arrays are statically allocated and not resizable in C++, so direct copying is not possible.

Comment: this is not possible, since `msg2`s size is only 4

Comment: `std::vector<uint8_t> msg2;`

Comment: I want to convert const char* msg1 to uint8_t msg2[]. 
Is it possible?

Comment: `msg2` is too small to contain the whole message. You would have to make it larger. `uint8_t msg2[20]`.

Comment: `uint8_t msg2[];` is an illegal declaration. An array size must be either specified or possible to determine from the initializer, but there's no initializer.

Comment: Or simply use the `std::string`.

Comment: @SukeshChand: Restating the question doesn't change the fact that the declaration `uint8_t msg2[]` is ***not legal C++***.

Comment: @NicolBolas; They changed the question.. again through more edits. But yes, you are correct as it stands right now.

Comment: @NicolBolas well, it's legal if it is a function parameter :) But if that's the context of the question, then they've forgotten to mention it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this is a 'C'ish question I used a C-style cast.

```
const char* msg1 = "hello how are you";
size_t length = strlen(msg1) + 1;

const char* beg = msg1;
const char* end = msg1 + length;

uint8_t* msg2 = new uint8_t[length];

size_t i = 0;
for (; beg != end; ++beg, ++i)
{
    msg2[i] = (uint8_t)(*beg);
}

std::cout << msg1 << "\n\n";
std::cout << msg2 << "\n\n";

delete[] msg2;
```

**Output:**

```
hello how are you

hello how are you
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is what I expected,

Comment: If you can do a small change I can mark as the accepted answer, The size of array must be dynamically set according to the size of msg1

Comment: like follows  

const char* msg1 = "hello how are you";
int l = strlen(msg1) + 1;
uint8_t msg2[l];

size_t i = 0;
const char* beg = msg1;
const char* end = msg1 + l;

for (; beg != end; ++beg, ++i)
{
    msg2[i] = (uint8_t)(*beg);
}
std::cout << msg1 << "\n\n";
std::cout << msg2 << "\n\n";

Comment: Done. I also rearranged the code a bit for logical clarity.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, msg2 is too small. But if it weren't (f.e. if you used: uint8_t msg2[MAX_LEN]):

```
 memcpy(msg2, msg1, strlen(msg1)+1);
```

If msg1 isn't const but variable, use something like that instead:

```
int l = strlen(msg1)+1;
uint8_t *msg2 = new uint8_t[l];
memcpy(msg2, msg1, l);
```

But remember to `delete []` it after using.

Comment: What happens if `strlen(msg1)` is greater than `MAX_LEN`?

Comment: MAX_LEN is (as name indicates) maximum possible length of msg1 (including terminator).

Comment: And how would you determine this? At *compile time*?

Comment: In the example, msg1 is literal, not variable. But ok, I'll correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> const char* msg1 = "hello how are you";
> uint8_t msg2[] = "hai";
> ```

In that example, it is impossible to copy all of `msg1` values into `msg2`, because `msg2` is too small. `msg1` points to an array of 18 characters. `msg2` is an array of length 4. 18 characters is more than 4.

Simplest solution is to use a vector. You can copy from an array into another using the following algorithm (pseudocode):

```
for each element in array at index i
    copy the element at index i into the back of the other array
```

There is no need to implement the algorithm yourself, as the standard library has already implemented it for you: `std::copy`. This works fine as long as the source type is implicitly convertible to the target type. If you need explicit conversion, then you can use `std::transform` instead.

> I want to copy into `uint8_t msg2[]`

There is no such type as `uint8_t[]`. You can use a regular array such as `uint8_t msg2[18]` of course, but you are limited to copying an array of length 18 or less. The size of a vector can be set at run time, so it doesn't have this limitation.

Comment: In what sense is `msg2` an array of length 4?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit see the quoted code from the question. It seems that the question has changed since I wrote the answer.

Comment: Okay, so it has.

Comment: `std::uint8_t` is defined in `<cstdint>`, or without the `std::` in `<stdint.h>`. They’re also in `<cinttypes>`/`<inttypes.h>`. It’s technically optional, but every existing implementation has it and it’s difficult to imagine anyone ever making another general-purpose CPU that doesn’t support octets at all.

Answer (score 1):

As written, you can’t extract the size of `msg1` as a compile-time expression, so you might want to write instead, `constexpr char msg1[] = "hello how are you";` so that you can then use `sizeof(msg1)` and get the size of the array, not the pointer.  You can then use that size as the bound for `msg2`.

If you don’t need the new array to be modifiable, you can just cast the pointer on any actually-existing implementation: `const uint8_t * const msg2 = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(msg1);`.  You can also cast it to a reference to an array the same size as `msg1` if you need the type to match exactly.  Or make the `msg1` array modifiable and alias it rather than copying.  Or initialize `msg2` to `{'h', 'e', ... }`.  Character constants are `int` values, so this is legal.

If you want to portably copy the elements of the array, you can either declare it the right size and `memcpy( msg2, msg1, MSG1_LEN )`, or you can write a loop that iterates over `msg1` and sets every `msg2[i] = static_cast<uint8_t>(msg1[i])`.  Or `push_back` every element of `msg1` into a `std::vector<uint8_t>`.